# Writing code for River Section Coordinates in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fluid-dynamics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYCIs.png)I got some problems with how i have to start writing the code. The problem is how i write fortran code to input the data of river section coordinates like using 'READ' as the command to input many coordinates in every sections with different shape. Maybe you guys can help me with that problems?.

i've tried writing the codes, but it doesnt work. I was expecting that the program work with just input the coordinate in many different river cross section while the code is compiling in fortran.

Comment: What is the format of the input data file?

Comment: @lastchance the data like entering the coordinates one by one depends on how many the river section we have

Comment: Nevertheless, if you want the cross-sectional area and wetted perimeter for any particular stage you are going to need a lot of coordinates. I should read them from file. Looking at your diagram, you will also need to make an early decision as to whether to supply them in imperial or metric units.

Comment: Your question is not really suitable for this site. This site is for specific programming questions. For example, for problems with some specific code - in that case the code and the errors must be shown. The words "it doesn't work" really do not say anything useful. You can also ask other things, like how to format input files to be read by some code, how to read some input files you have or similar, but you really need to be more specific.